# Expose stdin and stdout of binary as TCP socket in Docker

Tags: docker, go, socat

With socat I can expose a binaries stdin/out as a socket for example like this:

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork EXEC:./mybinary,pty
```

I would like to do the same with for example the go docker image.
But I can't run `CMD [ "socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork EXEC:/mybinary,pty" ]` because in the go image there is no `socat` tool and I see now way to install it.

Full error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork EXEC:/mybinary,pty": stat socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork EXEC:/mybinary,pty: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

Is there an elegant/intended way to do this in Docker?

Edit: My Docker File: (The project itself is just the most generic stdin/stdout echo-server you could imagine)

```
FROM golang:1.18

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY *.go ./

RUN go build -v -o /mybinary

CMD socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork EXEC:/mybinary,pty
```

Comment: Try adding `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y socat` to your Dockerfile

Comment: I can't because there is no apt-get in that image too. But even if it was possible. I feel like there has to be a better solution than this

Comment: Nevermind: there is apt-get. I don't know what I did before

Comment: Unfortunately another error arose: When running the image above with `CMD [ "/mybinary" ]` everything works fine. However the CMD with socat in my question gives me a `file /mybinary not found error`. But this is probably a completely different issue

Comment: You also could approach this using a [multi-stage Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/); add a second stage `FROM ubuntu:20.04` without the Go toolchain, and `COPY --from=build /mybinary /usr/local/bin` to get the built application.  You can `apt-get install` whatever you need into that final image, and it'll be much smaller.